# Google Drive Access Api Issue

Tags: google-drive-api

I am able to access google drive folder using google drive api but i could not access images and did not get ImageId within folder

If we pass static Access_token then it will be expire after 3000 seconds, So after that what we have to do ? I tried so many thing but did not get proper result, Can anyone help me to access google drive folder children id

Comment: Can you provide the code you use, error logs you received? Also for additional information, in drive [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) there is a Class Children: list that lists a folder's children. To list all children of the root folder, use the alias root for the folderId value. Hope it helps!